# Сохранение положения ячеек в TableView swift 4.2

Tags: swift

День добрый,
Есть TableView и я хотел сделать сохранение позиций ячеек
Пример: в TableView всего 30 ячеек, Прокрутил я допустим на 14 ячейку и закрыл программу и после запускаем заново программу и позиция ячеек сохранилась

Пытался сделать

```
let index = self.userDefalts.object(forKey: "position") as! Int
// index записывается в методе cellForRowAt indexPath
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

но прокрутка меня такая не устраивает - хочется чтобы как закрыл так и открыл, а сейчас нижняя ячейка делает сдвиг

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public struct UserDefaultsKeys {
static let keyForTableOffset = "DEFAULTS_FOR_CONTENT_OFFSET"
}
```

В методе `func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)`
Сохраняйте положение таблицы.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(tableView.contentOffset.y, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.keyForTableOffset)
defaults.synchronize()
```

А в методе `override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)`
Загружайте `offset`

```
if defaults.object(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.keyForTableOffset) != nil {
        let offsetY = defaults.object(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.keyForTableOffset) as! CGFloat
        print(offsetY)
        tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: offsetY), animated: false)
    }
```

//Update--------------------------

Решение через `background`

Все методы делегата UIScrollView удаляем.

В `override func viewDidLoad()`

Подписываемся на

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
```

Реализуем метод.

```
@objc func appMovedToBackground() {
    defaults.set(tableView.contentOffset.y, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.keyForTableOffset)
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: Спасибо
Бывает что происходит сдвиг после загрузки

Comment: Опишите более детально, что сдвигается?

Comment: scrollViewDidEndDragging срабатывает примерно после сантиметра прокрутки, вот и получается что если я прокрутил 0.9 см то он не сохранит

Comment: Если не брать в расчет симулятор, то что-бы закрыть приложение надо войти в background. Обновил ответ.